# Understanding fetching mutiple URLs and documents using curl

Tags: linux, command-line, curl, documentation, brace-expansion

It's not clear to me how to fetch multiple documents using `curl` mainly because I do not fully understand the explanation in the `curl` documentation

The curl documentation says:

> ```
> -o, --output <file>
>               Write output to <file> instead of stdout. If you are using {}  or  []  to  fetch
>               multiple  documents,  you  can use '#' followed by a number in the <file> speci‐
>               fier. That variable will be replaced with the current string for the  URL  being
>               fetched. Like in:
>
>                curl http://{one,two}.example.com -o "file_#1.txt"
>
>               or use several variables like:
>
>                curl http://{site,host}.host[1-5].com -o "#1_#2"
> ```

- Which part of the `curl` command does "variable" in the above blockquote refer to?
- The blockquote shows that you can specify multiple URLs for curl to fetch with:
  `http://{one,two}.example.com`.
  Does using `{}` cause the full URL above to expand to:

```
http://one.example.com
http://two.example.com
```

before `curl`'s fetch operation begins?

The `curl` documentation also says that:

> ```
>         or you can get sequences of alphanumeric series by using [] as in:
>
>          ftp://ftp.example.com/file[1-100].txt
>
>          ftp://ftp.example.com/file[001-100].txt    (with leading zeros)
>
>          ftp://ftp.example.com/file[a-z].txt
> ```

- I'm guessing `[]` also performs an expansion just like `{}` but does the remote file name have to be exactly `file1, file2, file3, ... file100`? i.e. does `file[1-100].txt` only work for file names with a numbered sequence, e.g. will using `file[1-100].txt` still work if rather than `file1, file2, file3,... file100` we have the files `file 1, file3 file5 ... file99` at that URL?
- Is using `[]` or `{}` the same as a shell expansion even though the curl documentation advises protecting `[]` or `{}` from shell expansion by surrounding the full URL with double quotes?:

  > ```
  > When using [] or {} sequences when invoked from a command  line  prompt,  you  probably
  >    have  to put the full URL within double quotes to avoid the shell from interfering with
  >    it. This also goes for other characters treated special, like for example '&', '?'  and
  >    '*'.
  > ```

Answer (score 3):

Many questions in one ...

- *Which part of the curl command does "variable" in the above blockquote refer to?*
  The `#1`, `#2` are the variables
- *Does using `{}` cause the full URL above to expand [...] before curl's fetch operation begins?*
  Yes, that's the brace expansion like done by the shell, but protected by quotes, so `curl` can perform the expansion.
- *I'm guessing `[]` also performs an expansion just like `{}` but does the remote file name have to be exactly `file1, file2, file3, ... file100`?*
  No, you can also give a step counter like `file[1-99:2]` for your example
- *Is using `[]` or `{}` the same as a shell expansion even though the curl documentation advises protecting [] or {} from shell expansion by surrounding the full URL with double quotes?*
  The `{}` syntax is the same as in brace expansion, the sequence expansion is different. The reason, why you need to protect it: If the shell would already do the expansion, how could `curl` know what the variables should be? If the shell expands `http://{one,two}.foo.com`, `curl` sees `http://one.foo.com` and `http://two.foo.com`, but no variable. If it sees the protected original, it knows the first variable `#1` to be either `one` or `two`.

Comment: Can you clarify your last point? Particularly what exactly replaces the variable in the example `curl http://{one, two}.example.com -o "file_#1.txt"`. If the expansion gives `http://one.foo.com` and `http://two.foo.com` and there is only one file, which url's output is written to the file? As for what replaces the variable I don't understand what *"the current string"* in *"That  variable will be replaced with the current string for the URL being fetched"* means. Does `curl http://{one, two}.example.com -o "file_#1.txt"` result in `file_http://one.foo.com.txt` or `file_http://two.foo.com.txt?`

Comment: `{one,two}` will make variable `#1` first take the value `one` and then take the value `two`, so `http://one.example.com` will be written to `file_one.txt` and `http://two.example.com` will be written to `file_two.txt`. *(Beware that the whitespace in your `{one, two}` would produce `two` with a leading space, which is certainly not what you want!)*